# Npm build for different webpack entries using parameter

Tags: npm, webpack

I want to know how to run a npm build for different webpack entries?

I have the following webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    assetsApp: "./assetsApp/src/index.js",
    pagesApp: "./assetsApp/src/index.js"
  }
...
```

I **want to avoid** creating different webpack configuration for each entry.

I wish something like this: `npm run build --app:assetsApp`

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your package.json to have separate scripts that specify the entry.

**package.json**

`scripts: {
  "build:assetsApp": "webpack ./assetsApp/src/index.js",
  "build:pagesApp": "webpack ./pagesApp/src/index.js"
}`

then run `npm run build:assetsApp` or `npm run build:pagesApp`

Don't forget to remove the entry object from your webpack config. For future reference `webpack --help` is a great quick resource.